# Relative path not working while accessing a sqlite Database through C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am creating a Excel Addin through which i want to access a database. code is as follows

```
    [ExcelFunction("My First Excel-DNA Function")]
    public static string GreetFunction(string name)
    {
        GetConnection();
        return "Hello" + " " + name;
    }

    public static void GetConnection()
    {

       //db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source="+System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)+"\\Database\\XLSQLiteDemo.sqlite");
        db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Database/XLSQLiteDemo.sqlite");
        try
        {
            db.Open();
            cmd = db.CreateCommand();
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Connection created");
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
           System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());       
        }
    }
```

so when i give absolute path like `c:/test/firstlibrary.../XLSQLiteDemo.sqlite` it works.

but when i use relative path like `db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Database/XLSQLiteDemo.sqlite");`

it throws an exception: `unable to open database file error code 14.`
the code which is in comment i.e.

```
//db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source="+System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)+"\\Database\\XLSQLiteDemo.sqlite");
```

also doesn't work i.e. it calculates the absolute path but when i tried to debug; debugging is automatically terminated after `db.Open();`
and output in excel sheet is also `#Value` which indicates some error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [With System.Data.SQLite how do you specify a database file in the connect string using a relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314853/with-system-data-sqlite-how-do-you-specify-a-database-file-in-the-connect-string)

Comment: i've changed the stmt to this 
db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=|DataDictionary|XLSQLiteDemo.sqlite");
still its nt wrking

Comment: What do you mean by 'debugging is automatically terminated after'? Without exception or what?

Comment: What is the actual path computed by the commented-out code?

Comment: Source=file:\\F:\\Test\\FirstLibrary\\FirstLibrary\\bin\\Debug\\Database\\XLSQLiteDemo.sqlite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@adrino may be the "file" word in your string is the problem.remove it.

```
       string relativePath = @"Database\XLSQLiteDemo.sqlite";
       string currentPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
       string absolutePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(currentPath, relativePath);
       absolutePath=absolutePath.Remove(0, 6);//this code is written to remove file word from absolute path
       string  connectionString = string.Format("Data Source={0}", absolutePath);
```

this works on my machine.tell me if its correct.